# Disable volume , back and call key

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Guys i'm working on a app currently which requires to disable the volume, back and call key. could you guys please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Comment: oh sorry i'm new to this site, i don't know that i have to accept a answer n all///